Error: Route.patch() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
Error: Route.patch() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
how i run this
Error: Route.patch() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
at Route. [as patch] (/Users/ghost/Desktop/SchoolManagmentSystem/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:216:15)
at proto. [as patch] (/Users/ghost/Desktop/SchoolManagmentSystem/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:521:19)
at Object. (/Users/ghost/Desktop/SchoolManagmentSystem/routes/authRoutes.js:9:8)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
